# Error transmitting callback function as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]/* I take only the important part of code */

Parent:
*/Here I create logic for my function */
`

```
const [allNoc,setAllNoc] = useState(0);

const allNocFunc = value => {
    console.log(value);
    setAllNoc(value);
  };`
```

*/In return I have my component with props */

`<SellectAllNoc dataList={resultDataList} allNocFunc={allNocFunc} />`

Child:

`function SellectAllNoc(dataList,allNocFunc) {const handleChange = () => {allNocFunc(2);};`

I want to sent value from child to parent by callback function

Answer (score 1):

If "Child" is meant to be a React component, this is not how you destructure props:

```
function SellectAllNoc(dataList,allNocFunc) {
```

This is:

```
function SellectAllNoc({ dataList, allNocFunc }) {
```

Basically, all of the props are passed to the component as a single object, with the prop keys/values being the properties on that object.  So in your code the `dataList` variable has two properties on it, called `dataList` and `allNocFunc`.  And in your code the `allNocFunc` variable isn't a function.  (I actually don't know if components receive a second argument in React, I've never used one.  So it may be `undefined`, or may be some unexpected value.)